# first argument from module (opcode llvm)

Tags: llvm, opcode

In https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/tree/main/llvm/examples/ModuleMaker is static variable.
How read argument module and put to Add instructions?

```
Instruction *Add = BinaryOperator::Create(Instruction::Add, x, y, "tmp");
```

how assign to x = argument block 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Function::arg_iterator argument = F->arg_begin();
Argument *Pierwszy = argument++;
Pierwszy->setName("c");
Value *Drugi = argument++;
Drugi->setName("d");
    
/* tworzymy instrukcję */
Instruction *Dodaj = BinaryOperator::Create(Instruction::Add,
Pierwszy, Drugi, "wynik");
```